# Zapier - how to use inputData with an array

Tags: javascript, zapier

I'm building a Zap which relies on some custom Javascript. I've got it properly working using this static part setting a variable:

```
var elements = [{"sku": "sku1", "quantity": "1", "unit_price": "10", "variant_code": "10", "ordernumber": "MAB01-00010"},{"sku": "sku2", "quantity": "2", "unit_price": "15", "variant_code": "15", "ordernumber": "MAB01-00010"}]
```

Please note, this is only a part of the code, but the other part is not relevant. At this point the entire code is doing exactly what I want but now I want to replace the data with some dynamic content from previous steps.

However, I can't get the dynamic content to work. I use variable "items" and insert the exact same value as working properly in the static example.

[inputData variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zdJ0W.png)

When I try to insert the variable, the code fails. I use `var elements = inputData.items` to insert the dynamic data into the code, but I think Zapier inserts it as a string instead of Raw characters, so the code crashes.

Does anyone have an idea how to insert this data using inputData?

Answer (score 1):

David here, from the Zapier Platform team. You're correct that all data comes in as a string. A `JSON.parse` should convert it back to an object:

```
const elements = JSON.parse(inputData.items)
```

In the future, make sure to post the actual error you're seeing, which will help others help you!

Comment: Should this still work. For me input data is displayed as serialized JSON in the UI but JSON.parse returns an error as if brackets were missing.

Comment: It should still work yes. why it doesn't really depends on what exact data is coming in. Post a question with your input and we can look!